# Trying to pass variables to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, I dont know why my codepen version and my real one act different, but they are.  In my codepen both windows start off with all of them open.  In my real version you only see 2 sets of **01-Postpone** and **02-Approve**, the way they should be.  Here, in my code snippet, the first text box does not populate, but the values are logged in the console.

Okay, so now my problem.  Clicking any 1 of these slides opens a box underneath it with 2 options.  PROCEED and CANCEL.  With my fun function, it gets the 3 variables perfectly when 1 of those options is clicked ( see them in my console).

When PROCEED is clicked, I need those 3 variables so that I can run an ajax post to an external file.  How do I get the 3 fun variables into my proceed function?  I thought with var, they would be global, but I have tried many possibilities without success to access them.  I do not want to use cookies as I am sure this is possible without them.

I have another freaky issue, but that is for another day when I get this part to work.  Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.

https://codepen.io/lepew/pen/agNBzo

```js
// 00 - CANCEL
function cancel00() {
  alert("Cancel");
}
// End CANCEL

// 02 - PROCEED
function proceed01() {
  // Ajax will go here
  alert("This works.");
}
// End of PROCEED

// 03 - Get the data-field variables
function fun(obj) {
  var one = obj.dataset.self,
    two = obj.dataset.record,
    three = obj.dataset.selectedoption;
  //
  console.log(one, two, three);
  //
}

//external file
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-link").on("click", function() {
    //
    const tranSpeed = "slow";
    //
    //
    // Get code variable and be able to access this value elsewhere.
    var selectmycode = $(this).attr("data-selectedoption");
    //
    // Display the variable in CONSOLE.
    console.log(selectmycode);
    //
    // Get clicked option.
    var selOption = $(this).data("selectedoption");
    //
    // Out the value of selectedoption into text field thecode.
    var thecoder = $(".thecode").attr("value", selOption);
    //
    //
    //
    // Get next "here".
    var here = $(this).closest(".bind_Name").next(".here");
    //
    // Populate stuff.
    $(here).find("legend").text(`Option ${selOption}`);
    //
    // TO DETECT IF DATA HAS CHANGED.
    var dataChanged = $(here).data("seloption") !== selOption;
    $(here).data("seloption", selOption);
    console.log(dataChanged)
    //
    // Show the dropdown if data changed.
    var target = $(here).find(".dropdown-container");
    //
    // This will close all other open options.
    $(".dropdown-container").not(target).hide(tranSpeed);
    //
    if (dataChanged) {
      $(target).show(tranSpeed);
    } else {
      // Or toggle it otherwise.
      $(target).toggle(tranSpeed);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bind_Area">
  <div class="bind_Name">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" onclick="fun(this);" data-selectedoption="01" data-record="123456820" data-self="123456830">01-Postpone
      </div>
      <!-- end of #dropdown-link -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of #dropdown -->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" onclick="fun(this);" data-selectedoption="02" data-record="123456820" data-self="123456830">02-Approve
      </div>
      <!-- end of #dropdown-link -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of #dropdown -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of #bind_Name -->
  <div class="here">
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <input type="text" class="thecode" data-code="">
        <input type="text" class="peter" data-user="123456820" value="123456820">
        <input type="text" id="mary" data-product="123456830" value="123456830">
        <div><a href="" onclick="return false" onmousedown="proceed01()">PROCEED</a></div>
        <div><a href="" onclick="return false" onmousedown="cancel00()">CANCEL</a></div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <!-- end of #dropdown-container -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of #here -->
  <div class="bind_Note"></div>
</div>
<!-- end of #bind_Area -->

<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="bind_Area">
  <div class="bind_Name">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" onclick="fun(this);" data-selectedoption="01" data-record="123456820" data-self="123456831">01-Postpone
      </div>
      <!-- end of #dropdown-link -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of #dropdown -->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" onclick="fun(this);" data-selectedoption="02" data-record="123456820" data-self="123456831">02-Approve
      </div>
      <!-- end of #dropdown-link -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of #dropdown -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of #bind_Name -->
  <div class="here">
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>
          <div class="fubar"></div>
        </legend>
        <div>
          <input type="text" class="thecode" data-code="">
          <input type="text" class="peter" data-user="123456820" value="123456820">
          <input type="text" id="mary" data-product="123456831" value="123456831">
        </div>
        <!-- end of #blank div -->
        <div><a href="" onclick="proceed01();">PROCEED</a></div>
        <div><a href="" onclick="cancel00();">CANCEL</a></div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <!-- end of #dropdown-container -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of #here -->

  <div class="bind_Note">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end of #bind_Area -->

<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqgbmM ?

Comment: WOW, perfect.  I see the global var is set before all the functions.  Thank you so much !!!